# if(!message.member.hasPermissions("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) NOT WORKING

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I have tried changing **if(!message.member.hasPermissions("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))** to multiple variations, yet none of them are working!! They used to work but don't now, please help. Discordjs version: 11.4.2

````
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let db = bot.db.get(message.guild.id);

  if (!args[0])
    return message.channel.send("How many messages do you want to prune?");
  if (parseInt(args[0]) > 100)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You can not prune more than 100 messages at a time."
    );

  if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Invalid permissions.")
  
  let channel = message.guild.channels.get(db.modlog);
  let wait = await message.delete();

  if (wait)
    message.channel
      .bulkDelete(Math.floor(parseInt(args[0])).toString())
      .then(() => {
        if ((args[0] = "1")) {
          message.channel
            .send(args[0] + " message pruned!")
            .then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
        } else {
          message.channel
            .send(args[0] + " messages pruned!")
            .then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
        }

        const log = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor("000000")
          .setAuthor(`n/`, bot.user.avatarURL)
          .addField(`User`, message.author.tag + " (" + message.author.id + ")")
          .addField(`Pruned Amount`, args[0])
          .addField(`Channel`, `<#${message.channel.id}>`);

        if (!db.modlog) return;
        bot.channels.get(channel.id).sendEmbed(log);
      });
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: "prune"
};```
````

Comment: "does not work" is not sufficient information to provide to receive help.
What's the expected (wanted) behaviour, what's the actual (unwanted) behaviour? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Lioness100 Hey! What I want is if somebody does the !prune command without correct permission, it tells them invalid permissions rather than executing the command. What's happening is I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is `hasPermission()`
EDIT: If wrong, because I use v12

Comment: I tried changing it to hasPermission() but it still gives me this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null`

Comment: If you want it: the line of code is: `if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Invalid permissions.")` @Double0Seven

Comment: i know this sounds silly, but u have defined message properly right? bc ur error message is basically saying message.member isn't a thing

Comment: it should be. i have no errors on any other command besides commands that use the function `hasPermission()` @Double0Seven

Comment: Well ur error basically says ‘I can’t do hasPermission() because I don’t know what message.member is’ so it must be an error with the parameters

Answer (score 0):

At some point after October 24th occurred, `message.member` now returns `null`. I'm having the same issue as well and have no idea if it is accidental or permanent.